# how to get all values of a column in the same order as shown

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas column named as user_id, and the data is in this format

```
[![enter code here][1]][1]
```

I want to get all these id's in the same order as seen. When i use top_10_users_df['user_id'].tolist(), the values return in different order which cannot be users

```
['09834de5-d21f-45f2-b1e9-aee2bcbb13db', '34fb3e5b-66f3-47b5-8ccc-6aebacbb5ccc', '378a4c00-20d5-4fa6-8d12-38b2ef646e5b', '3a522ec5-34ad-4013-8b86-cdedf7b3ae4b', '4c49a7df-9c23-4f2d-8249-1fe60f6d7b25', '5365ef22-136b-460e-bcf9-84ca42570d29', '5d4daff8-9df1-4c0f-a9ee-7808a5d0fedb', '9f3bed3b-df74-4e37-9732-3858a6f433ea', 'ef15a0c7-b7bd-4475-8bcf-38325fc79578', 'f1599709-5d8e-4b85-bbcc-5055e0015379']
```

which unfortunately is not useful for me, can someone help and tell the exact order to retrieve these values. Thanks !

Comment: Your code block does not appear to be formatted correctly. Can you please correct the post so we can offer assistance with your problem? A screenshot of your issue is also quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code block doesn't seem to have formatted properly. A list should always be printed in the same order. If you want to have some consistency maybe you can use:

```
sorted(my_list)
```